# ClosedXML: Access existing pivot table

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, closedxml

I created a workbook, added data to a sheet and from that data created a pivot table on another sheet. I would like to be able to open said table on another occasion later in the code, but I can't figure out how to do this. Using this:

```
IXLPivotTable pivot = pivotSheet.PivotTables.PivotTable("temp");
```

or

```
IXLPivotTable pivot = pivotSheet.PivotTable("temp");
```

does not work, even though the table's name is *temp*. I even used the Open XML SDK Tool to read the XLSX file's XML code and found out that indeed the table is named *temp*.

What am I doing wrong here? It always throws a System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException on said line of code, i.e. it can't find the table.

Comment: Loading pivot tables from an existing file is not yet supported in ClosedXML. It's on our to-do list.

Comment: I've created a pull request to handle loading of basic pivot tables. Note that not all pivot table features are supported yet. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/124